# Semi-Definite Program to maximise $P(X)$ with a fixed CHSH value

Tags: programming, probability, bell-experiment, semidefinite-programming

This question should be theoretically simple, yet I'm struggling as something may be incorrect about my code. I am trying to plot a graph of the maximum probability ($P(x)$) of a given system against CHSH violation values. We can do this using the expectation values through the NPA moment matrix and create an SDP where I maximise $(1+\langle A_0 \rangle)/2$. This should give me $P(0)$. The constraints lie in making sure the correct elements of the moment matrix sum up to a given CHSH value and the matrix is positive semi-definite.

However, I get values of 1 for all values of the inequality. Rather the curve should be around 1 for values 2 or less and curve to 1/2 for maximum violations of the CHSH Bell inequality (this is for two measurements). Are there more constraints to be added or am I missing something?

````python
chsh_values = np.linspace(2, 2*np.sqrt(2), 100)
max_px_values = []
for chsh in chsh_values:
    # Define the moment matrix (5x5 for this setup)
    M = cp.Variable((5, 5), symmetric=True)

    # Objective function: Maximize (1 + <A0>) / 2
    objective = cp.Maximize((1 + M[0, 1]) / 2)

    # CHSH constraint
    constraints = [ 
                M[1, 3] + M[2, 3] + M[1, 4] - M[2, 4] == chsh, 
                M[0, 0] == 1, M[1, 1] == 1, M[2, 2] == 1, M[3, 3] == 1, M[4, 4] == 1,
                M >> 0,
                ]

    # Solve the problem
    prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
    prob.solve(solver=cp.MOSEK)
       
    max_px_value = prob.value
    max_px_values.append(round(max_px_value, 3))

    # Print the moment matrix and the maximum value
    print(f"CHSH Value: {chsh}")
    print("Moment Matrix:\n", M.value)
    print("Maximum (1 + expectation of A0) / 2:", max_px_value)
    print("--------------------------------------------------")
```
````

Comment: Do you know for certain that level 1 of the hierarchy should exhibit this behaviour? I would try level $1+AB$, i.e., add the $A_xB_y$ operators into the indexing set, probably you will start to see a difference then.

Comment: @Rammus
Seems as though this is the solution as I've tried the commonLisp approach written by Erik Woodhead. At level 2+ this given me correct solution. What I'm failing to understand is exactly how higher levels work and how their respective moment matrix look like. If you could explain this that would be great. Examples are always useful